# using mDNS, no router, ipv6 on ubuntu gets "Invalid Argument"

Tags: ubuntu, routes, ipv6, mdns

I'm trying to set up an appliance to announce its service using mDNS, and connect to it with no infrastructure or router or DHCP.   It works perfectly between raspberry pi and OSX.   Not so between raspberry pi (running ubuntu with hostname 'ubuntu.local') and ubuntu 14.02 on intel.   Here's a run down of my most focused test, from the command line of ubuntu on intel, after clearing out the routes on ubuntu.

```
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ ip -6 route list 
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ sudo traceroute -i eth0 ubuntu.local
traceroute to ubuntu.local (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
connect: Network is unreachable
```

so -- no routes, right?  Let's add one and try again:

```
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ sudo ip -6 route add fe80::/10 dev eth0
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ sudo traceroute -i eth0 ubuntu.local
traceroute to ubuntu.local (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  ubuntu.local (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5%eth0)  0.925 ms  0.988 ms  1.058 ms
```

Now I have a route and have demonstrated that ubuntu on intel knows the ipv6 address of ubuntu.local, and can talk to it.   Note that I forced the use of the eth0 interface.  Let's try it without specifying the interface, since the route I added should send all fe80* traffic out eth0:

```
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ sudo traceroute ubuntu.local
traceroute to ubuntu.local (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
connect: Invalid argument

jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ ssh -6 ubuntu.local
ssh: connect to host ubuntu.local port 22: Invalid argument
```

without specifying an interface, I get "Invalid Argument".   Various tests with ssh, wget, etc all return 'invalid argument'.  If I force the interface again, using the ipv6 address of the raspberry pi (ubuntu.local) appending %eth0, I can connect.

```
jeff@jeff-OptiPlex-SX280:~$ ssh -6 ubuntu@fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5%eth0
Password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.18.0-14-rpi2 armv7l) 

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Fri Mar 20 20:56:52 2015 from fe80::20f:1fff:fee2:2c36%eth0
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ exit
logout
Connection to fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:74e5%eth0 closed.
```

Syntactically, I can't seem to append the interface to the mDNS name, ssh will complain.  It seems like the "Invalid Argument" is an artifact of trying some device other than eth0, but I can't confirm.   Am I just missing the point on ipv6 routing?  I've got no gateway in this use case, so a lot of advice I see doesn't apply.  I tried making the raspberry pi the gateway with no different outcome.

Thanks for your advice!

-Jeff

Comment: When working with link-local IPv6 addresses, you MUST include the scope since you will have the same network on any and all interfaces in IPv6. The OS needs to know which network you mean, and it uses the scope ID to determine this. A DNS name should be a routable IPv6 address, not a link-local address, since link-local addresses cannot be routed. This may be the source of your problem. Assign one or more routable addresses to your interfaces and try that.